# FuelPHP ORM find('all') get only one row

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

When i use FuelPHP ORM to get ALL results using find('all'), it's return only one record.

This is my db.
table name ws_config. (no primary key)

```
--------------------------
config_name | config_value |
--------------------------
site_name | My Site |
--------------------------
member_allow_register | 1 |
--------------------------
```

This is my model.

```
class Model_Config extends Orm\Model 
{
    protected static $_table_name = 'config';
    protected static $_primary_key = array();// no PK, need to set PK to empty array.
}
```

This is my controller

```
class Controller_Account_Register extends \Controller_Basecontroller 
{
    public function action_index() 
    {
        $config = Model_Config::find('all');
        $output['config'] = $config;

        // call function below is in base controller. it is just load theme (this view page into main template) nothing special.
        return $this->generatePage('front/templates/account/register_v', $output);
    }
}
```

This is my view file.

```
foreach ($config as $row) {
    //print_r($row);
    echo $row->config_name;
    echo ' = ';
    echo $row->config_value;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

The result is just

site_name = My Site

How to get ALL results from this database table? or 
How to get multiple results upon where ondition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that indeed as @vee says the ORM expects you to have a primary key assigned to your table. By default in the orm this is simply a column called "id". If you do not specify a PK unexpected behaviour happens, such as this.

Once you define a primary key on your table this issue should be resolved.

The simplest thing would be to just add an auto-incrementing ID column as this is the default for orm models.

Comment: Come to think of it you could use your `config_name` column as the PK

Answer (score 0):

FuelPHP ORM needs Primary key to get ALL results.

No PK you can get only one result.

erm... :(

Comment: @trippino I would say it does answer the question, and the answer is, add a PK to the table.

Comment: The reason for this is that the hydration process used the primary key as an index value. When no PK is available, all records will have the same index value (null), and all results will overwrite each other. So the one result you get is that last record in your query resultset.